# Javascript .innerHTML won't work

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, getelementbyid

I ran into some problems this morning with a piece of JavaScript code, i can't seem to get the .innerHTML thing to work, this is what i've wrote:

```
<script>
    var curtime = new Date(),
    curday = curtime.getDate(),
    curmonth = curtime.getMonth()+1;

    if(curmonth == 10 && curday == 14)
        document.getElementById(titel).innerHTML = "nieuw";

</script>
```

it's in the `<head>` tag. Somewhere in the `<body>` i have this:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/rushter/"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><p style="display: inline;" id="titel"> Rushter</p></a>
</div>
```

why doesn't this work? the javascript does work when i replace the document.getElement... part with a simple alert.

ps. yes i'm a javascript noob

Comment: `getElementById("titel")`, Pass ID in quotes

Comment: also you should execute this piece of code after the DOM has been loaded (in onload or put this script after the div declaration)

Comment: Debug your code. Start off by viewing the console and seeing what errors are being printed.

Answer (score 1):

you may get syntax error, change or define the `titel` as variable and assign `id` name then you could use

`document.getElementById(titel)`

to

`document.getElementById("titel")`

although, if the code inside `<head>` tag then use [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event otherwise add code beneath element that is using inside JavaScript code

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var curtime = new Date(),
    curday = curtime.getDate(),
    curmonth = curtime.getMonth()+1;

    if(curmonth == 10 && curday == 14)
        document.getElementById("titel").innerHTML = "nieuw";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter of document.getElementById is a string value of the element's ID.

```
document.getElementById('titel').innerHTML = "nieuw";
```

Answer (score 0):

Enclose your id value in quotes (double or single).

```
document.getElementById("titel");
```